# Signup Form with AJAX-Submission in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having some headaches solving this issue. I have a Wordpress / Woocommerce Signup Form which fires a couple of actions in order to work. In addition to those actions I want to post the form data to a CRM. It is working fine independently but not together.

Here is the Form Markup:

```
<form id="bc_post-register" method="post" class="register">

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_action_one' ); ?>

  <input placeholder="E-Mail*" type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ); ?>" />
  <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="Kostenlos einschreiben" />

</form>

 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_action_two' );?> 
 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_action_three' );?>
```

Here is my AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {
   jQuery('#bc_post-register').submit(ajaxSubmit);
   function ajaxSubmit() {
   var ConvForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
  type:    "POST",
  url:     "https://app.crm.com/directory/id/action",
  data:    ConvForm,
  success: function(data) {
     console.log("has been sent");
  }
});
return false; 
} 
});
```

It's all working beautifully but not together. How can I bring the puzzle together and fire the Actions and my AJAX?

Comment: What errors are you getting? OR, what is it not doing.

Comment: can you please post your action.php script.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. AJAX is working fine and PHP is working as it is supposed to as well. I will just need a way to do both here. Run the actions and the call / Kind of a double submit.

Answer (score 0):

I made some subtle changes.  Also, make sure that you have jQuery installed.

Try this and see if it helps:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(event){ 

  $('#bc_post-register').submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); //Prevents your from submitting/refreshing.
    var string = $('#bc_post-register').serialize();

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://app.crm.com/directory/id/action.php", //added the .php
          data: string,
          dataType: 'json', //The response needs to be a json formatted string.
          cache: false,
          success: function(response){

            console.log('This is your response: ' + response);

          }else{

            console.log('There was a problem submitting your ajax.');  

            }
      });

  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Hey there, there is not really a problem with the AJAX here the AJAX is working beautifully but the form should als do the actions defined in do_action( 'woocommerce_action_one'). So we will need a "double submit" kind of,

Comment: I think I am going to have to defer to someone who knows WP better than I.